# How to check what element the draggable hovers over?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hover, draggable

Is there a way in jQuery UI to check which element the dragged draggable is hovering over, using the `tolerance` settings?

This is not to use with droppable.

Comment: Sorry just posted an answer and saw it was not what you require

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hover event for all elements

```
var elem = null;
$('*').hover(function() {elem = this});
```

**OR**

better than this give your elements underneath your draggable item a specific class, I assume you just want the element underneath to just detect the item is hovering over it?

```
var elem = null;
$('.Underneathdraggable').hover(function() {elem = this});
```

this will give you the current item under your mouse cursor